# convert csv file from UTF-8 to ANSI encoding

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I am getting data from a db table which was in array. So i am using the below code to write that data into csv . in the array we will have some data related to utf-8. But i need the file encoding type should be ANSI. Because the other side system will accept only ANSI encoding files. Below is my code.

```
$fh = fopen($new_file, 'w+');
header('Content-Encoding: Windows-1252');
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=Windows-1252');
foreach($input as $curl_response)
{
    fputs($fh, implode($curl_response, ';')."\n");
}
// ... close the "file"...
fclose($fh);
```

After generating csv file when i open that in notepad and choose save as option it is showing me as UTF-8. Where i am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just setting the content header won't change the actual encoding of the data. You need to decode, then re-encode.

Comment: Also, is this PHP or what? Please tag your post with the programming language you are using, it'll help potential answerers.

Comment: yes, this is PHP